# MKSNT sh.exe throws parsing error inconsistently when invoked from windows gmake

Tags: windows, sh, gnu-make, mks

**Environment**

Windows

MKSNT

gmake

Makefile relevant part (very simplified)

```
rules.mk
%.lib: 
    if [ "$(notdir $(@D))" = "opt" ]; then \
      gmake test.obj; \
    else \
      gmake test2.obj; \
    fi
```

- When i run my make file i get this error **inconsistently**

> ```
>  opt was unexpected at this time.
> ```

I ran "process monitor"  and traced it and found this is mostly thrown by gmake when it invokes sh.exe

```
  C:/mksnt/mksnt/sh.exe -c "if [ opt = \"opt\" ]; then  gmake test2.obj;   else  gmake test.obj fi"
```

**Question**

- What puzzles me is why is this inconsistent. Sometimes it succeeds. Sometimes it fails.
- Possibly sh.exe has issue parsing that part. But why and why is it inconsistent

Comment: Sorry I don't have `gmake` experience. But can you add a line above the test, just to print what value is being processed for  `"$(notdir $(@D))"` ? Good luck.

Comment: - Thanks. It is resolved to 'opt'. That is already in the sh.exe command line I gave. The error comes from sh.exe. Also I can see in process monitor sh.exe errors out with non-zero exit code. But this issue reproduces inconsistently

Comment: so you get `"opt"` even when you get the error? Is the failing process using non-local disk space? If so, could the error be due to a network hiccup? (Just an idea). Good luck!!!

Comment: I don't have access to mksnt at the mo, but "was unexpected at this time" seems like an error from `cmd` not `sh` (though perhaps mksnt sh produces the same error)?  The line you provide from procmon does not match the Makefile you provided (I know you said you simplified it).  Can you enable debugging in `gmake` and provide us with the exact command that gmake is executing that produces the error?